# Build Status Notification In Stash From Jenkins with Build No as tag

Tags: git, jenkins

Is it possible for Jenkins to set up a Tag on the git repository (branch its building) with the build number ?
This would avoid the manual tasks we need to carry out currently.

This would give us traceability of whats deployed from that build with the code snapshot.
Which can be pulled in later stage in case of any issue needing hotfix.
please suggest

Comment: I know about git publisher plugin but don't know to use it

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use one of the Jenkins plugins you could use the manual git commands inside an execute shell post-step?

```
git tag -a ${BUILD_NUMBER} -m <message for that tag>
```

If you did want to use the Git Plugin with jenkins that on the panel where you enter the repository you should select "Advanced Actions" and in there there is an option to "Create a tag for every build" which should do what you require